# Webstorm LiveEdit not updating js files

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, node.js, phpstorm, webstorm

When I am attempting to change my node server code and view it to live edit, I use the following address: http://localhost:63342/untitled4/app.js
but instead of the code running, I just get a text version of the code itself.

I want to be able to write new server code and immediately test it without having to restart a server or the chrome page. I've been using the debug session but only HTML changes have been working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a browser + the built-in web server to test the server code? For running server-side code, please use node.js interpreter. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/running-and-debugging-node-js.html.

Note that live editing node.js is also supported - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#ws_node_debug_live_edit, https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/10/live-edit-for-node-js-in-phpstorm-8/